Websphere jython: How to clear messages in specific queuepoint SIBus
Sometimes cause of system intermitten or stop abnormal, hung thread, so messages stills in queuepoint of SIBus, these messages looks like dead messages, they cant continue processing also cant clear.
In websphere console (Service integration > Buses > MyBus > Messaging engines > Queue point > Messages) I could selected all messages then delete them.
Could any solutions to use jython scripts to clear all messages on specific queuepoint above ?
Each services applications we spilit into cluster, each JVMs has unique bus and InputQueuePoint and ReplyQueuePoint to consume messages.
Thanks bro
